# Decryption using System.Net.Security.Cryptography with the key

Tags: c#, cryptography, .net-4.5

I have the below code to decrypt an encrypted cipher using the old Microsoft.Web.Services2.Security.Cryptography. How will I achieve the same using System.Net.Security.Cryptography class?

```
public byte[] DecryptData(byte[] EncryptedData, System.Security.Cryptography.RSA rsaKey)
{
    Microsoft.Web.Services2.Security.Cryptography.RSA15EncryptionFormatter eFormatter = new Microsoft.Web.Services2.Security.Cryptography.RSA15EncryptionFormatter(rsaKey);
    return eFormatter.Decrypt(EncryptedData);
}
```

**EDIT**
The code I use is below. But this does not decrypt the cipher. I do not have access the encryption methods. So I do not know what is the real text to see.

```
    public byte[] DecryptData(byte[] encryptedData, System.Security.Cryptography.RSA rsaKey)
    {

        try
        {
            var csp = new RSACryptoServiceProvider(rsaKey.KeySize);
            return csp.Decrypt(encryptedData, false);                
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            //debugger; //No exception here.
        }
    }
```

Comment: "This does not decrypt the cipher" is not a good error description.

Answer (score 0):

You use the [`RSACryptoServiceProvider.decrypt`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.rsacryptoserviceprovider.decrypt%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) method, where the second parameter is `false`.

Comment: could you provide a code sample. I could not find it anywhere without the vector parameter.

Comment: You are using the public key to encrypt and a private key to decrypt, right?